# On the Schrödinger equation and the eigenvalue problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory

- [Li-Yau 1983_Article](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01213210.pdf)
- The second part of above paper used the discrete eigenvalues of $\frac{-\Delta}{q}$  where  $q>0$ to proof the the number of non-positive eigenvalues of
  Schrödinger operator $-\Delta+V$ can be bounded by the $L_{\frac{n}{2}}$-norm of $V^-$.
- My question is: under what condition of $q$ can we proof the spectrum of $\frac{-\Delta}{q}$ is discrete.

Comment: you'll probably get a better response if you ask a self-contained question, which does not require first reading an article off-line...

Comment: In order to show that the spectrum is discrete, you consider the inverse of the operator $-\Delta/q$ and show that it is compact and self-adjoint over some Hilbert Space. There is a standard example involving the Laplacian in Brezis' book on Functional Analysis. You can just modify that proof and deduce what conditions are required for $q$.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker，sorry, I didn't explain my question clearly, actually my question has nothing to do with this paper.

Comment: @ nls , you are right, now I think I should have solved this problem by myself, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $q>0$ the Schroedinger operator $-\Delta/q$ is associated to the form $a(u,v)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n, q\, dx)$. The form domain consists of all $u\in L^2(\mathbb R^n, q\, dx)$ such that $u \in \dot H^1:=\{u \in L^{2^*}(\mathbb R^n), \nabla u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)\} $ and the discreteness of the spectrum is equivalent to the compactness of the embedding of the form domain into $L^2(\mathbb R^n, q\, dx)$.

This follows when the map $$T:\dot H^1 \to L^2(\mathbb R^n), \quad Tu=q^{1/2}u$$ is compact, which is true whenever $q \in L^{n/2}$.

Comment: @Giorgio Metafune thanks, I get it.